# Pushing/Sending MySQL changes to clients

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, real-time

**The Goal:**

What I am trying to do is when the MySQL database has changed send the changes to the clients currently connected.

I was thinking of trying to accomplish this using websockets however the only implementation I have seen of this is a client sends something to server and the server sends that to all the other clients.

**What I am trying to do is the client connects to server (That's all the client has to do) then whenever the server has seen a change in the mysql database sends the changes to all the clients.**

If websockets is the best solution could someone possibly explain how I would implement that? Or if there is a better way then websockets what is it?

Comment: What do you mean with "server has seen a change in the mysql database" ? What kind of change - schema or data changes?

Comment: Data change like a new record was added or was removed or changed

Comment: Think this is possible with some poling mechanism on each client, monitoring any new feed of data through a socket connection. Wouldn't just reading a database table at a frequent interval accomplish the same?

Comment: In your use case is the database behind a REST API? If so and if data can only be updated through that API you could easily update the data and on success publish the update into the websocket of each subscribing user (or you could use a pub/sub managed cloud service to that for you, like Pusher or Realtime.co)

Comment: Yes, I do have REST API behind the database. This is the way I have it setup. 
1. A client will send data to a table in the database using the REST API. 
2. On the server I have a cron job that processes the data the clients have sent, and updates another table. (When that table gets updated I would like to notify all the clients of the change so the app will update the data in real time.) 
3. Rather then the client having to call the server every second asking if new data is available. (Which is what I do as of now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for that i can give you my code because i think websocket is the best way to do it easy.
and Now,what I am trying to do is the client connects to server  then whenever the server has seen a change in the MySQL database sends the changes to the specific clients(something like : save the id client get it from database in cookie then send it to the server to check the right client in order to show for him the new data).

Check [this](https://github.com/GianlucaGuarini/nodejs-MySQL-push-notifications-demo) link

Comment: link given above is dead